# After loading a config struct into go, problems with accessing nested properties

Tags: go, struct, interface, yaml

So I want to load into my program a `config.yaml` file into my programm.

```yaml
defaultTimeout: 0.25
defaultWorkspace: ibm
workspaces:
  ibm:
    client: 47943938
    defaultGoal: 27.5
    projects:
      - 159929907
      - 160046030
      - 160064503
  pp:
    defaultGoal: 5.5
    project: 160064503
```

Therefore I create following struct:

```golang
type Config struct {
    DefaultTimeout   float64 `yaml:"defaultTimeout"`
    DefaultWorkspace string  `yaml:"defaultWorkspace"`
    Workspaces       struct {
        IBM struct {
            Client      int     `yaml:client`
            DefaultGoal float64 `yaml:"defaultGoal"`
            Projects    []int   `yaml:"projects"`
        }
        PP  struct {
            DefaultGoal float64 `yaml:"defaultGoal"`
            Project     int     `yaml:project`
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, I have different workspaces listed with different properties and one property in common: the `DefaultGoal`. Now I want to access this property in a clean and efficient way.

Now I have the parameter `*workspaceName` that decides which workspace I want to choose. So the question is how I use this as a key which `Workspace` I want to choose and then further get the `DefaultGoal` of the respective entry?

I tried the following (`config` is the struct loaded from the yaml source)

```
wsConf := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(config.Workspaces)).FieldByName(*workspaceName)
```

But then I have `reflect.Value` that I have to cast back into a struct to assess `DefaultGoal`.

Is there a good way to proceed here? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should probably just make the workspaces a `map` instead of using a bunch of overcomplicated reflection to access them.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. So I guess you mean use a `map` instead of a `struct` for `Workspaces`? 
I actually did not know that you can load a `yaml` config into a `map` but I can test it out!

Comment: @Adrian I just testet it and I think this is not possible without changing the structure of the `yaml` file.

Comment: that's definitely not true. I can't say what you'd need to change though because I have no idea what you tried.

Comment: You can view my approach here: https://play.golang.org/p/hwFcKHh-W2z
It is just using structs and no maps. But it does not help me to avoid duplicate code when calling `wsConf.DefaultGoal`. And Im sorry but I do not see how maps can help about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than playing with a reflection (`reflect` package) it might be much easier to use `map[string]interface{}` as a field type (specifically `Workspaces` field) and then treat item from this map as a specific workspace.

```
type Config struct {
    DefaultTimeout   float64 `yaml:"defaultTimeout"`
    DefaultWorkspace string  `yaml:"defaultWorkspace"`
    Workspaces       map[string]interface{} `yaml: workspaces`
}

type IBM struct {
            Client      int     `yaml:client`
            DefaultGoal float64 `yaml:"defaultGoal"`
            Projects    []int   `yaml:"projects"`
}
type PP struct {
            DefaultGoal int `yaml:"defaultGoal"`
            Project     int `yaml:project`
}

func main() {
    var cfg Config
    // init cfg somehow
    for space, value := range cfg.Workspaces {
        switch space {
        case "ibm": // convert `value` to IBM struct
        case "pp": // convert `value` to PP struct
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your approach and I realized that I used a similar approach previously.
It is not a bad approach and probably better than using reflections (because they do not solve my problem either).
But still this does not solve the core Idea: How can I use the converted structs outside of the `switch` statement? I want to apply the same functions to both structs. (e.g. querying for `DefaultGoal`)

Comment: @Tillus I've had good luck with https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method if you want to unmarshal into specifc structs based on `Workspace` name. (The extra marshal step is generally not needed when using json. More [here](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/issues/13)). Working example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/8gsL96GLEzR)

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Config struct {
    DefaultTimeout   float64 `yaml:"defaultTimeout"`
    DefaultWorkspace string  `yaml:"defaultWorkspace"`
    Workspaces       map[string]interface{}
}

type PP struct {
    DefaultGoal int `yaml:"defaultGoal"`
    Project     int `yaml:"project"`
}

type IBM struct {
    Client      int     `yaml:"client"`
    DefaultGoal float64 `yaml:"defaultGoal"`
    Projects    []int   `yaml:"projects"`
}

func main() {
    yamlData := `defaultTimeout: 0.25
defaultWorkspace: ibm
workspaces:
ibm:
    client: 47943938
    defaultGoal: 27.5
    projects:
    - 159929907
    - 160046030
    - 160064503
pp:
    defaultGoal: 5.5
    project: 160064503`

    var c Config
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlData), &c); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for space, value := range c.Workspaces {
        bs, err := yaml.Marshal(value)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        switch space {
        case "ibm":
            var i IBM
            if err := yaml.Unmarshal(bs, &i); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            log.Printf("IBM value: %v", i)

        case "pp":
            var p PP
            if err := yaml.Unmarshal(bs, &p); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            log.Printf("PP value: %v", p)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!
But right now when I test it the map is empty. (
`fmt.Println(c): {0.25 ibm map[]}`

Comment: @Tillus are your sure? I have updated the code above. [Here's](https://play.golang.org/p/QYX9RgNSqpg) the update playground link.

Comment: Ah yes now it is working :)
This is already a helpful example thank you. If there would be a way how to combine the `var i IBM` and `var p PP` in one interface that I could query for `DefaultGoal` that would be awesome and would reduce code duplicity. But maybe I am expecting a bit too much there.

Comment: I think I can do the functionality without any maps so far: https://play.golang.org/p/hwFcKHh-W2z

Comment: @Tillus if you want to make it via interface, `type Workspace interface { Goal() interface{} }` will be enough. Goal can be as a `float` and as a `string` so we need to unite them under "any" (type) which is interface. And than just cast to what do you need exactly.